Title: How to output changed registers and ESP in red color after each `p` command in Windbg using JavaScript?
I'm trying to write a JavaScript script for Windbg that outputs the changed registers and ESP in red color after each p command. I want to achieve this by comparing the current register values with the previous ones and highlighting the differences.
Here's what I have so far(with chatgpt):
"use strict";

let logln = function(e) {
  host.diagnostics.debugLog(e + '\n');
};

let prevRegs = {};
let prevEsp = null;

function handle_p() {
  let Regs = host.currentThread.Registers.User;
  let esp = Regs.esp.toString(16);

  let changedRegs = {};
  let changedEsp = false;

  // Check for changed registers
  for (let reg in Regs) {
    if (Regs.hasOwnProperty(reg)) {
      let regVal = Regs[reg].toString(16);
      if (!prevRegs[reg] || prevRegs[reg] !== regVal) {
        changedRegs[reg] = regVal;
      }
    }
  }

  // Check for changed ESP
  if (prevEsp === null || prevEsp !== esp) {
    changedEsp = true;
  }

  // Output changed registers and ESP
  if (Object.keys(changedRegs).length > 0) {
    logln("Changed registers:");
    for (let reg in changedRegs) {
      if (changedRegs.hasOwnProperty(reg)) {
        let regVal = changedRegs[reg];
        logln(reg + "=" + regVal);
      }
    }
  }

  if (changedEsp) {
    let espDump = host.currentThread.Registers.User.readMemoryValues(Regs.esp, 16);
    logln("Changed ESP: " + esp);
    logln(espDump.join(' '));
  }

  // Update prevRegs and prevEsp
  prevRegs = Object.assign({}, Regs);
  prevEsp = esp;
}

function invokeScript() {
  let Control = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control;

  // Check if a breakpoint is already set
  let BreakpointAlreadySet = Control.ExecuteCommand('.printf "%mu", "p"').indexOf("p") !== -1;

  if (BreakpointAlreadySet === false) {
    let Bp = Control.SetBreakpointAtOffset("p", 0, "ntdll");
    Bp.Command = '.echo doare; dx @$scriptContents.handle_p(); gc';
  } else {
    logln('Breakpoint already set.');
  }

  logln('Press "g" to run the target.');
}

However, when I try to execute this script in Windbg, I encounter an error related to host.utilities.control. How can I fix this issue or achieve the desired functionality in a different way?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

AFAIK it's not possible. You would need DML color output but this is not accessible from JS. Although, for ex. .printf /D can output dml, you'd need to ExecuteCommand on .printf and then debuglog the output, but then the output looses the DML capabilities... this is a bummer since the feature is there, but it's not usable directly from JS :(

@Neitsa correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think even DML allows you to specify arbitrary colors. You have to pick from their predefined color scheme, and AFAIK, there's nothing red in it.
